# Add Macro to all Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have a macro that I want to save for all my past, current, and future Google sheets as this is a repetitive task that I constantly have to do. For some reason, I can't seem to figure out how to save my macro to other google sheets.

Comment: You're describing an add-on. You'll have to publish it (privately is an option).

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros at this time it's not possible to add a macro to all spreadsheets. The alternative is to create an add-on.